# Query to find the maximum relation between two fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

With the following database structure:

> movies_directors (director_id: int, movie_id: int)
>   roles (actor_id: int, movie_id: int, roles: string)

How do I ﬁnd the actor(s) with whom the directors have collaborated on the most movies?

```
directors_id, actor_id
```

The result I am getting after trying the query is:

DIRECTOR_ID   ACTOR_ID COLLABORATIONS

---

```
    101          1              2
    102          6              1
    105          4              1
    101          2              1
    104          8              1
    101          3              1
    103          7              1
    100         11              1
    101         10              1
    100          5              1
    104          2              1
```

DIRECTOR_ID   ACTOR_ID COLLABORATIONS

---

```
    101          9              1
```

I just need a combination of every director with an actor having the max movies together. For example for director_id 101  only 101 1 2 entry should be displayed.

Comment: Show us **every possible combination** [you've tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: mysql and sql-server? Which are you using here?

Comment: @hd1 I am using Sql server

Comment: how do you know that directors have collaborated on the most movies?

Comment: @ JW we can find out that by comparing the movie ids in the 2 tables.

Comment: Then why did you have this question tagged with MySQL?

Comment: can you give us sample records and your desired result?

Comment: So you are looking for every director, and the actor that has collaborated with them on the most movies (i.e. per director)?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use TDQD — Test-Driven Query Design.

#### Q1: Which directors worked with which actors

The first step is establish which directors worked with which actors on movies, which is found by joining the two tables on the Movie_ID column:

```
SELECT d.Movie_ID, d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID
  FROM Movies_Directors AS d
  JOIN Roles AS a
    ON d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
```

Since you've not told us about the primary keys of the tables, we cannot tell whether a single actor can be recorded as having several different roles in a single movie or not.  I'm going to assume that the primary key of the Roles table is the combination (Movie_ID, Actor_ID).

#### Q2: How many times did each director work with each actor

We need to count the number of rows for each combination of actor and director, based on the query above:

```
SELECT d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) AS num_joint_movies
  FROM Movies_Directors AS d
  JOIN Roles AS a
    ON d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
 GROUP BY d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID
```

#### Q3: For each director, what is the maximum number of times they've worked with an actor

We now need to find the maximum number of joint movies for each director from the result above.  This needs to treat the query above as table, like this:

```
SELECT n.Director_ID, MAX(n.num_joint_movies) AS max_joint_movies
  FROM (SELECT d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) AS num_joint_movies
          FROM Movies_Directors AS d
          JOIN Roles AS a
            ON d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
         GROUP BY d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID
       ) AS n
 GROUP BY n.Director_ID
```

#### Q4: Which actor(s) have worked the most with each director

Now we need to combine queries Q2 and Q3 to get the actors too:

```
SELECT q3.Director_ID, q2.Actor_ID
  FROM (SELECT n.Director_ID, MAX(n.Num_Joint_Movies) AS Max_Joint_Movies
          FROM (SELECT d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) AS Num_Joint_Movies
                  FROM Movies_Directors AS d
                  JOIN Roles AS a
                    ON d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
                 GROUP BY d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID
               ) AS n
         GROUP BY n.Director_ID
       ) AS q3
  JOIN (SELECT d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) AS Num_Joint_Movies
          FROM Movies_Directors AS d
          JOIN Roles AS a
            ON d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
         GROUP BY d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID
        ) AS q2
     ON q3.Director_ID = q2.Director_ID AND q3.Max_Joint_Movies = q2.Num_Joint_Movies
```

#### Q5: Use a common table expression (CTE)

The SQL standard allows for common table expressions, introduced with a WITH clause, to simplify queries like this:

```
WITH cte AS
    (SELECT d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) AS Num_Joint_Movies
       FROM Movies_Directors AS d
       JOIN Roles AS a
         ON d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
      GROUP BY d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID
    )
SELECT q3.Director_ID, cte.Actor_ID
  FROM (SELECT cte.Director_ID, MAX(cte.Num_Joint_Movies) AS Max_Joint_Movies
          FROM cte
         GROUP BY cte.Director_ID
       ) AS q3
  JOIN cte
    ON q3.Director_ID = cte.Director_ID AND q3.Max_Joint_Movies = cte.Num_Joint_Movies
```

---

#### Q6: Maximum number of collaborations for any director

Since the question has been altered a bit since I started answering, the results shown above may not be precisely what is required — though the revised question does not make it clear what is required.  However, the general technique of breaking down the question into answerable sub-queries is valuable; it is how I'd approach any similar query.  If you are looking for the single combination of Director + Actor that have collaborated the most, then we need to modify Q3 to find the maximum number of joint movies across all directors:

```
SELECT MAX(n.num_joint_movies) AS max_joint_movies
  FROM (SELECT d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) AS num_joint_movies
          FROM Movies_Directors AS d
          JOIN Roles AS a
            ON d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
         GROUP BY d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID
       ) AS n
```

#### Q7: The actor(s) plus director(s) who've collaborated the most often

And we now need to combine Q6 with Q2 again:

```
SELECT q2.Director_ID, q2.Actor_ID
  FROM (SELECT MAX(n.Num_Joint_Movies) AS Max_Joint_Movies
          FROM (SELECT d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) AS Num_Joint_Movies
                  FROM Movies_Directors AS d
                  JOIN Roles AS a
                    ON d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
                 GROUP BY d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID
               ) AS n
       ) AS q3
  JOIN (SELECT d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) AS Num_Joint_Movies
          FROM Movies_Directors AS d
          JOIN Roles AS a
            ON d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
         GROUP BY d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID
        ) AS q2
     ON q3.Max_Joint_Movies = q2.Num_Joint_Movies
```

Comment: You can also do it with `APPLY`, which will be cleaner: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/04/13/the-power-of-t-sql-s-apply-operator.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `max()` function for this.

```
SELECT
max(collaborations) 
FROM movies_directors mov 
INNER JOIN roles r 
     on r.movie_id=mov.movie_id 
GROUP BY mov.director_id,r.actor_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concise way to accomplish what you want:

```
  select top (1) with ties
    M.director_id,
    R.actor_id,
    COUNT(movie_id) as MovieCount
  from movies_directors as M
  join roles as R
  on M.movie_id = R.movie_id
  group by
    M.director_id,
    R.actor_id
  order by rank() over (
  partition by director_id
  order by COUNT(movie_id) desc
  )
```